# "The received size" vs "The size of the received data"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, verbs, adjectives, american-english

I know `The size of the received data` is a correct phrase. I just wonder:

Can I use the shorter and concise form: `The received size`?

Is it grammatically correct?

Will a native speaker think it natural?

Comment: Please do not use computer code markdown for mentions. It looks terribly wrong. Use italic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Received size" (or "size received") is grammatically correct and could be used in this example:

"I gave the message about the required size to the radio operator and he sent it using Morse code. But something must have gone wrong because the size sent was 6 but the size received was 66."

In the above example it can be said that the thing received is actually the size itself. If however size is simply one of many attributes of the thing (in this case data) received then I do not think it would be correct to say "received size" and you need to say "the size of the data received"

Where size is not merely an attribute, but is a common identifier, of the thing itself - e.g. in the case of clothing and footware - in that case you could use "size received" as in the following example:

"I ordered the shoes but the shop sent ones which were too small. The size I ordered was 10 but the size I received was 9."

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the data? If you're talking about an Excel spreadsheet or something, perhaps not, though if you're talking about the size of a download or something, then yes, I think the meaning of `the received size` is perfectly apparent, if used in the correct context

Comment: Please do not use computer code markdown for mentions. It looks terribly wrong. Use italic.